# What is a standard way to quickly deploy a LAMP installation with a virtual host and certbot?

Tags: apache-httpd

Say I rent an IaaS environment and want to quickly deploy a LAMP installation with a virtual host and SSL certificate by Bash alone (no programs such as Ansible would be used).

Is there some standard way to do so?

Comment: It looks to me a little bit open-ended or unclear. But I think you can use some minimalistic VM image and upload it from bash (from most providers).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the details. What do you understand on "LAMP installation", it is a specific set on configs of apache/mysql/php, or it is a custom system image?

Considering that it is an IaaS setting, logic dictates you have a LAMP system (as a VM image or a compressed fs) and you want to deploy it into some VM container. To my best knowledge, there is not even an usual way to do that. All it depends on your VM provider. Very likely, you need to get some command line interface from your provider, and you need to deploy things to it.

Another possible interpretation of your question, that you have an actually running virtual machine, and you want to deploy your LAMP configuration to that. There, things depend on the distro, however in the current devops world, typically containers are deployed.